# issue with Hive Serde dealing nested structs

Tags: json, struct, hive

I am trying to load a huge volume json data with nested structure to hive using a Json serde. some of the field names start with `$` in nested structure. I am mapping hive filed names Using `SerDeproperties`, but how ever when i query the table, getting null in the field starting with `$`, tried with different syntax,but no luck.

**Sample JSON:**

```
{
    "_id" : "319FFE15FF90",
    "SomeThing" : 
    {
            "$SomeField"     : 22,
            "AnotherField"   : 2112,
            "YetAnotherField":    1
    }
 . . . etc . . . .
```

Using a schema as follows:

```
create table testSample
( 
    `_id` string, 
    something struct
    <
        $somefield:int,
        anotherfield:bigint, 
        yetanotherfield:int
    >
) 
row format serde 'org.openx.data.jsonserde.JsonSerDe' 
with serdeproperties
(
    "mapping.somefield" = "$somefield"
);
```

This schema builds OK, however, somefield(starting with `$`) in the above table is always returning null (all the other values exist and are correct).

We've been trying a lot of syntax combinations, but to no avail.

Does anyone know the trick to hap a nested field with a leading `$` in its name?

Comment: couple of things i can suggest you: 1) convert `$somefield:int` to `'$somefield':int` in the `create table` command. 2) try with a different JsonSerDe, for e.g., https://github.com/electrum/hive-serde

Comment: let me know if any of this helps

Answer (score 2):

You almost got it right. Try creating the table like this.
The mistake you're making is that when mapping in the serde properties (mapping.somefield ="$somefield") you're saying "when looking for the hive column named 'somefield', look for the json field '$somefield', but in hive you defined the column with the dollar sign, which if not outright illegal it's for sure not the best practice in hive.

```
create table testSample
(
`_id` string,
something struct
<
    somefield:int,
    anotherfield:bigint,
    yetanotherfield:int
  >
)
row format serde 'org.openx.data.jsonserde.JsonSerDe'
with serdeproperties
(
"mapping.somefield" = "$somefield"
);
```

I tested it with some test data:

```
{ "_id" : "123", "something": { "$somefield": 12, "anotherfield":13,"yetanotherfield":100}}
hive> select something.somefield from testSample;
OK
12
```

Comment: Sorry my bad, it was a typo in the post($somefield:int), but actually declaration code is fine. so for data like{ "_fld1": { "$fld1": "12345"},"fld2": "ABCD" }                                                                                                                table is created with:CREATE TABLE Temp(`_fld1` struct<dfld1:string>, fld2 string)     ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.openx.data.jsonserde.JsonSerDe'          WITH SERDEPROPERTIES ( "mapping.dfld1" = "$fld1"), but when i selected the table field dfld1, it is always null, am i missing something. Thanks

Comment: it works fine for me using the table definition and data you provided, but I had to put _fld1 around backticks (\`_fld1\`): 
hive> select * from temp;
OK
{"dfld1":"12345"} ABCD
Is it the actual definition you're using or just simplifying it ?
What version of serde/hive/hadoop are you using ?

Comment: this also works fine for me: 
hive> select \`_fld1\`.dfld1 from temp;
OK
12345

Comment: I have issue with field names starting with $, it is returning null all the time. I am using Hive version 1.1.0 and Hadoop 2.6.0 on CDH 5.5.0. I think i am using latest hive json serde only as i downloaded it recently.Thank you so much for your help & time.

Comment: ok, so to make sure it's a version specific issue, could you get these files: http://www.congiu.net/files.zip , it has the create.sql and  data.txt that I used. Have a look at them and run 
hive -f create.sql (it will drop the 'temp' table and re-create it) and let me know if it works for you. Also, the jar for the serde should have the version number as well, but I don't know where it's installed in your system.

Comment: Hi, it is working fine for the data you provided, but not working for my data.{ "_id" : { "$id1" : "12345" }, "name" : "name1", "location" : { "$city" : "City", "$addr" : { "$str" : "Street Drive" } }, "Zip" : [ 43016 ] }   . The SerDe version i am using is 1.3.7. Please let me know what i am doing wrong. your help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Could you also add your CREATE statement including the exact SERDEPROPERTIES you're setting ? As you see from my example, the feature in the serde works fine, so it must be a minor detail.

Answer (score 0):

I am suddenly starting to see this problem as well but for normal column names as well (no special characters such as $)

I am populating an external table (Temp) from another internal table (Table2) and want the output of Temp table in JSON format. I want column names in camel case in the output JSON file and so am also using the Serdepoperties in the Temp table to specify correct names. However, I am seeing that when I do Select * from the Temp table, it gives NULL values for the columns whose names have been used in the mapping.

I am running Hive 0.13. Here are the commands:

Create table command:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE Temp (
    data STRUCT<
        customerId:BIGINT, region:STRING, marketplaceId:INT, asin:ARRAY<STRING>>
) 
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.openx.data.jsonserde.JsonSerDe' 
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES ( 
    'mapping.customerid' = 'customerId',
    'mapping.marketplaceid' = 'marketplaceId'
) 
LOCATION '/output'; 

INSERT INTO TABLE Temp
    SELECT 
        named_struct ('customerId',customerId, 'region', region, 'marketplaceId', marketplaceId, 'asin', asin) 
    FROM Table2;
```

Select * from Temp:

```
{"customerid":null,"region":"EU","marketplaceid":null,"asin":["B000FC1PZC"]}
{"customerid":null,"region":"EU","marketplaceid":null,"asin":["B000FC1C9G"]}
```

See how "customerid" and "marketplaceid" are null. Generated JSON file is:

```
{"data":{"region":"EU","asin":["B000FC1PZC"]}}
{"data":{"region":"EU","asin":["B000FC1C9G"]}}
```

Now, if I remove the with serdeproperties, the table starts getting all values:

```
{"customerid":1,"region":"EU","marketplaceid":4,"asin":["B000FC1PZC"]}
{"customerid":2,"region":"EU","marketplaceid":4,"asin":["B000FC1C9G"]}
```

And then the JSON file so generated is:

```
{"data":{"region":"EU","marketplaceid":4,"asin":["B000FC1PZC"],"customerid":1}}
{"data":{"region":"EU","marketplaceid":4,"asin":["B000FC1C9G"],"customerid":2}}
```