# Athena AWS bad field name and multiple folders with Hive DDL

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, hive, amazon-athena

I'm new into AWS Athena, and I'm trying to query multiple S3 buckets containing JSON files. I encountered a number of problems that don't have any answer in documentation (sadly their error log is not informative enough to try to solve it myself):

1. How to query a JSON field named with parenthesis? For example I have a field named "Capacity(GB)", and when I'm trying to include in the CREATE EXTERNAL statement I receive an error:

> ```
>    CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS test-scema.test_table (
>   `device`: string,
>   `Capacity(GB)`: string)
> ```
>
> Your query has the following error(s):
>
> FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask.
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Error: : expected at the position
>   of 'Capacity(GB):string>' but '(' is found.

2. My files are located in sub folders in S3 in a following structure:

   'location_name/YYYY/MM/DD/appstring/'

and I want to query all the dates of a specific app-string (out of many). is there any 'wildcard' I can use to replace the dates path?
Something like this:

> `LOCATION 's3://location_name/%/%/%/appstring/'`

3. Do I have to load the raw data as-is using CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE, and only then query it, or I can add some WHERE statements build-in? Specifically is someting like this is possible:

> ```
> CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS test_schema.test_table (
>   field1:string,
>   field2:string
>   )
>
> ROW FORMAT SERDE  'org.apache.hive.hcatalog.data.JsonSerDe'
> WITH SERDEPROPERTIES (
>   'serialization.format' = '1'
> ) LOCATION 's3://folder/YYYY/MM/DD/appstring'
>
> WHERE field2='value'
> ```

What would be the outcomes in terms of billing? Cause right now I'm building this CREATE statement only to re-use the data in a SQL query once-again.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1.  JSON field named with parenthesis**

There is no need to create a field called `Capacity(GB)`. Instead, create the field with a different name:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE test_table (
    device string,
    capacity string
)
ROW FORMAT  serde 'org.apache.hive.hcatalog.data.JsonSerDe'
with serdeproperties ( 'paths'='device,Capacity(GB)')
LOCATION 's3://xxx';
```

If you are using **Nested JSON** then you can use the Serde's `mapping` property (which I saw on [issue with Hive Serde dealing nested structs](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34536294/174777)):

```
CREATE external TABLE test_table (
   top string,
   inner struct<device:INT,
               capacity:INT>
   )
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.openx.data.jsonserde.JsonSerDe'
with serdeproperties
(
"mapping.capacity" = "Capacity(GB)"
)
LOCATION 's3://xxx';
```

This works nicely with an input of:

```
{ "top" : "123", "inner": { "Capacity(GB)": 12, "device":2}}
```

**2. Subfolders**

You cannot wildcard mid-path (`s3://location_name/*/*/*/appstring/`). The closest option is to use [partitioned data](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/partitions.html) but that would require a different naming format for your directories.

**3. Creating tables**

You cannot specify `WHERE` statements as part of the `CREATE TABLE` statement.

If your aim is to reduce data costs, then use [partitioned data](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/partitions.html) to reduce the number of files scanned or store in a column-based format such as Parquet.

For examples, see: [Analyzing Data in S3 using Amazon Athena](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/analyzing-data-in-s3-using-amazon-athena/)

Comment: It becomes more complicated because my JSON is nested. For instance: {device:213123, custom:{capacity(GB):8.2, ID:34242}}
How should I write the paths in this case?

Comment: I've added an example of using Nested JSON with the `Capacity(GB)` field, which tested fine for me.

Comment: The parenthesis problem was solved perfectly, but the subfolders problem is frustrating. It seems that I cant partition the data since my folders stucture is `/YYYY/MM/DD/APP/` and not `/year=YYYY/month=MM/day=DD/app=APP/` is there is any way to solve it automatically?

Comment: Correct. All sub-folders will be used. If you wish to partition, you will need the filename-format. You can point it to a sub-folder level (eg `/YYY/MM/DD`) and it will read files and folders below that level, but you can't partition at the `/*/APP` level.

Comment: How should I partition it correctly so queries such as:
`WHERE app='appid'` will run only on the needed partition?

Comment: You would need to have your directory structure as `/app=abc/*` or `/app=abc/year=2017/month=4/day=7/*`.

Comment: sadly, I don't have control over the directory structure